# ATK 4.2 Auth with MD5 won't match password

Tags: atk4

When using Basic Auth with md5 encryption in 4.2, it won't let me log in.

doing a bit of debugging, the problem seems to be in the encryptPassword function in Auth_Basic in this statement:

```
    if(is_callable($this->password_encryption)){
       $e=$this->password_encryption;
        return $e($password,$salt);
    }
```

with md5 being a callable function, this is getting the password encrypted and the data back in raw format, meaning it won't match with the db record.

commenting this bit out makes it all work fine.

gregs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
if(!is_string($this->password_encryption) && is_callable($this->password_encryption)){
    $e=$this->password_encryption;
    return $e($password,$salt);
}
```

and let us know if it works?